# MySQL stored procedure did not insert data despite return ID

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to mysql stored procedure. I've been trying to insert data via the store procedure I created below. The procedure does return @USER_ID. However, the procedure does not insert data into the table.

//stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_USR_PROFILE_InsProfile(
IN FIRST_NAME varchar(50),
IN LAST_NAME varchar(50),
IN EMAIL_ADDRESS varchar(50),
IN PASSWORD varchar(256),
IN DOB date,
IN GENDER varchar(10),
IN TIMEZONE varchar(100),
IN NATIONALITY_ID int(11),
IN RESIDENCE_CTRY_ID int(11),
IN ADDRESS_LINE1 varchar(200),
IN ADDRESS_LINE2 varchar(200),
IN ADDRESS_LINE3 varchar(200),
IN PO_BOX varchar(50),
IN CITY_TOWN varchar(50),
IN POSTCODE_ZIP varchar(50),
IN STATE_PROVINCE_REGION VARCHAR(50), 
IN DESCRIPTION varchar(500),
IN PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME varchar(50),
IN PROFILE_IMAGE_LOCATION varchar(100),
IN LAST_UPDATED_USER int(11),
OUT USER_ID int(11))
BEGIN

--table with only auto increate col
INSERT INTO SEQ_USR_PROFILE_USER_ID(ID) VALUES (NULL);

SELECT @USER_ID := MAX(ID) FROM SEQ_USR_PROFILE_USER_ID;

    INSERT INTO TBL_USR_PROFILE (
        USER_ID,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        PASSWORD,
        DOB,
        GENDER,
        TIMEZONE,
        NATIONALITY_ID,
        RESIDENCE_CTRY_ID,
        ADDRESS_LINE1,
        ADDRESS_LINE2,
        ADDRESS_LINE3,
        PO_BOX,
        CITY_TOWN,
        STATE_PROVINCE_REGION,
        DESCRIPTION,
        CREATED_DATE,
        PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME,
        PROFILE_IMAGE_LOCATION,
        STATUS_ID,
        LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
        LAST_UPDATED_USER)
    VALUES (
        @USER_ID,
        @FIRST_NAME,
        @LAST_NAME,
        @EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        @PASSWORD,
        @DOB,
        @GENDER,
        @TIMEZONE,
        @NATIONALITY_ID,
        @RESIDENCE_CTRY_ID,
        @ADDRESS_LINE1,
        @ADDRESS_LINE2,
        @ADDRESS_LINE3,
        @PO_BOX,
        @CITY_TOWN,
        @STATE_PROVINCE_REGION,
        @DESCRIPTION,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        @PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME,
        @PROFILE_IMAGE_LOCATION,
        1, -- STATUS ACTIVE
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        @LAST_UPDATED_USER)

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

//the execution

```
CALL `USP_USR_PROFILE_InsProfile`('System Administrator', '', 'test@test.com', '1234567', '2015-08-09', 'MALE', 'Universal Time', '1', '1','','','','','','','','','','',0, @USER_ID);
```

//table creation

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TBL_USR_PROFILE`;

CREATE TABLE `TBL_USR_PROFILE` (
  `RUNNING_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `EMAIL_ADDRESS` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `DOB` date NOT NULL,
  `GENDER` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `TIMEZONE` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `NATIONALITY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RESIDENCE_CTRY_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS_LINE1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS_LINE2` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADDRESS_LINE3` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PO_BOX` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY_TOWN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POSTCODE_ZIP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATE_PROVINCE_REGION` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROFILE_IMAGE_LOCATION` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_DATE` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATED_USER` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `RUNNING_ID` (`RUNNING_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Appreciate if any one can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: What you are doing is inherently wrong.

- There is a race condition between `INSERT INTO SEQ_USR_PROFILE_USER_ID(ID) VALUES (NULL);` and `SELECT @USER_ID := MAX(ID) FROM SEQ_USR_PROFILE_USER_ID;`, that might end up in using the wromng user id.
- Using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` would avoid that
- Using a transaction would also avoid that

Now for the code: The first thing that springs to the eye is that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a function, so you would need to write `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`.

I also recommend droping the sequence table and using `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the user table directly, with the ID easily given back by `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @USER_ID := MAX(ID) FROM SEQ_USR_PROFILE
```

Is your first line. Your function will return that regardless of the return ( or even existence) of the insert statement